# How to change text color and font in px.timeline

Tags: python, plotly

Not really a specific code issue, it's just I can't find how to edit text size and font in a px.timeline, neither for go.bar.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.subplots as sp

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
dict(unit='MVT',Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
dict(unit='MVT',Task="Job B", Start='2009-02-28', Finish='2009-04-15'),
dict(unit='MVT',Task="Job A", Start='2009-04-15', Finish='2009-05-30')
])

fig1 = px.timeline(df1, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish",y="unit",color="Task",text="unit")
```

How to do if I have to have bold text for example

Comment: Which text? title, axis, the ticks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the text inside each bar through `insidetextfont`:

```
fig1.update_traces(insidetextfont=dict(color='white', size=16,family='Times New Roman'))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `insidetextfont` was not working but it worked with `textfont`.

Comment: @Johann but it worked with me as you see it. Which plotly version do you have?

Comment: 5.9 :/ . I see i am not up to date, the latest version is 5.11.